# List the selected files in template table angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor, angular2-components

I am new to angular 2. Trying to list the file name in template table selected from the browser. Below is my code

---

**Template.html**

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" style="display: none" (change)='onClickUploadDocument($event)' multiple>
<label for="uploadFile"  class="btn btn-primary">Upload Documents</label>
<table cellpadding="4" class="grid" >
<thead><tr><th></th><th>Document Name</th><th>Document ID</th><th>Document Type</th><th>Source</th><th>Notes</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let file of files">
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
    <td >{{file.name}}</td>
    <td>DC2352</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
        <td>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> 
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> 
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {NgClass} from '@angular/common';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
    selector: 'documentManagement',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/features/documents/documentManagement/documentManagementTemplate.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NgClass]
})

export class DocumentManagementComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    files: any[];

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    ngOnChanges(): void {}

    onClickUploadDocument(event){
        console.log("clicked");
        var file = event.target.files;

        console.log(file);
        for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            var fileInfo = file[i];
            console.log(fileInfo);
            this.files = fileInfo;
        } 

    }
}
```

---

I am getting following error if I try to apply *ngFor

**Error**

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object File]' of type 'Jellyfish.jpg'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
        at new BaseException (exceptions.ts:14)
        at NgFor.Object.defineProperty.set [as ngForOf] (ng_for.ts:48)
        at DebugAppView._View_DocumentManagementComponent0.detectChangesInternal (DocumentManagementComponent.template.js:386)
        at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.ts:243)
        at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.ts:345)
        at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.ts:267)
        at DebugAppView._View_DocumentControlPanelComponent3.detectChangesInternal (DocumentControlPanelComponent.template.js:467)
        at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.ts:243)
        at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.ts:345)
        at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (view.ts:261)
```

---

Can someone tell what is the mistake and a solution for this? THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onClickUploadDocument` you set `this.files` to `fileInfo` instead of pushing it to your array. 
Since your `files` property is declared as `any` type, your compiler doesn't report this as an error.

`*ngFor` only accepts arrays, so you get this error, because at this point, `files` is just a string (which the error tells you as well).

So to solve this you can edit your `onClickUploadDocument` function like this:

```
...

this.files = []; // clear the array before pushing your values into it.

for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
     let fileInfo = file[i];
     console.log(fileInfo);
     this.files.push(fileInfo);
}

...
```

(I used `let` here because it's considered best practice.) 
Additionally you should declare your property `files` with a "real" type declaration instead using any (if you not definitely want it to be `any`) like this: `files:string[];`

Hope it helps.